# rails undefined method on form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

i have model `User` and `Gallery`

`user has many gallies` and `gallery belongs to User`

models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :galleries
end

class Gallery < ApplicationRecord
  has_many_attached :files
  belongs_to :user
end
```

on my controller :

```
class GalleryController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @gallery = Gallery.new
  end

end
```

and then on `gallery/new.html.haml` :

```
.container
  %h4
    New Gallery
  %div
    = form_for @gallery do |f|
      .form-group
        = f.label :title, class: 'col-md-2 col-form-label'
```

then when i go to localhost:3000/gallery/new 
it said :

```
undefined method `galleries_path' for #<#<Class:0x00007f9f4e865908>:0x00007f9f4ae31b10>
Did you mean?  gallery_path
```

but when i command that for_for and change it to some text Hellow word, the page was just fine,
is there something i missing here ??

i am using ruby 2.7.1 and latest Rails
[image: full error here]

routes:

```
                      gallery_index GET    /gallery(.:format)                                                                       gallery#index
                                      POST   /gallery(.:format)                                                                       gallery#create
                          new_gallery GET    /gallery/new(.:format)                                                                   gallery#new
                         edit_gallery GET    /gallery/:id/edit(.:format)                                                              gallery#edit
                              gallery GET    /gallery/:id(.:format)                                                                   gallery#show
                                      PATCH  /gallery/:id(.:format)                                                                   gallery#update
                                      PUT    /gallery/:id(.:format)                                                                   gallery#update
                                      DELETE /gallery/:id(.:format)                                                                   gallery#destroy
```

Comment: could you share the rest of the gallery/new.html.haml and the rest of the error log please

Comment: @Suhirthan just update the rest of html and the pic full error

Comment: I think maybe you don't have the routes defined for the resources or could be that the gallery/edit.html.haml is not defined. My bet is mostly to do with the routes.

Comment: Can you share of output for `rails routes | grep galler` ?

Comment: @AlexGolubenko just updated check above

Comment: @Suhirthan i did on routes.rb = `resources :gallery`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you called `resources :gallery` and not `resources :galleries`. Which generates the wrong routes:

```
                  gallery_index GET    /gallery(.:format)  gallery#index
```

The argument to `resources` should always be the plural form.

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :galleries
end
```

---

```
                           Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
                        galleries GET    /galleries(.:format)                                                                     galleries#index
                                  POST   /galleries(.:format)                                                                     galleries#create
                      new_gallery GET    /galleries/new(.:format)                                                                 galleries#new
                     edit_gallery GET    /galleries/:id/edit(.:format)                                                            galleries#edit
                          gallery GET    /galleries/:id(.:format)                                                                 galleries#show
                                  PATCH  /galleries/:id(.:format)                                                                 galleries#update
                                  PUT    /galleries/:id(.:format)                                                                 galleries#update
                                  DELETE /galleries/:id(.:format)                                                                 galleries#destroy
```

Your controller name should also be plural:

```
# app/controllers/galleries_controller.rb
class GalleriesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /galleries/new
  def new
    @gallery = Gallery.new
  end
end
```

As should the views folder:

```
$ mv app/views/gallery app/views/galleries
```

Comment: did you meant i should change in route : `resources :galleries` ??  after i list the routes again, all routes gonna to galleries#index and bla...., should i change name of controller to be Galleries also??

Comment: Yes the controller name should also be plural.

Comment: it reallt work thanks for the help and explanations, so to make sure again, if i have has_many, should i create plural name ?

Comment: Yes, the name of have_many and HABTM assocations should always be plural while has_one and belongs_to are singular.